# Sounds settings changed on own and can't be reset

Tags: iphone

A few weeks ago my sound settings changed on their own, and I cannot seem to reset them; I change it and it doesn't save once I go out of Settings.

I go into Settings > Sounds > I change Vibrate on Silent to OFF and change New Mail to NONE and go back out and they immediately revert to ON and DING.

Phone also still vibrates when the side button is on Orange (Silent).  Very annoying.  Phone is less than 2 years old.

I have tried rebooting phone and this does not work.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how I can get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try an hard-reset by pressing the Home and Lock buttons simultaneously in 10 seconds and then release them. Your phone will now restart and you will not lose any data.
2. Do an reset of all settings. To do this: Make sure you have a backup of your phone first or know the important settings for you. Then you go to the "Settings" application -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings. When you reset all settings, only the settings, no files will be affected.
3. Try reseting the whole phone and restoring it from an iCloud or iTunes back-up. To do this: Make sure you backed up everything to iCloud or your computer (don't forget the pictures). Then you make a reset from "Settings" application -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content and Settings.

Did it work? Didn't it? If you have any further questions, please ask in the comments.